# What is $L^p(\{0,1\})$ ? i.e. a $L^p$ space on two points?

Tags: lp-spaces

What is $L^p(\{0,1\})$ ? i.e. a $L^p$ space on two points ? I'v never heard about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the space of all functions $f\colon\{0,1\}\longrightarrow\mathbb R$, endowed with the norm$$\|f\|_p=\left(\bigl\lvert f(0)\bigr\rvert^p+\bigl\lvert f(1)\bigr\rvert^p\right)^{\frac1p}.$$Of course, it is basically $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the norm $\lVert\cdot\rVert_p$.

Comment: Oh I see. But why writing $L^p\{0,1\}$ instead of $(\mathbb R^2, \|\cdot \|_p)$ ? It's so confusing... But as the writing suggest, is it a "non convex" norm ? (but may be it's not a norm but maybe $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|_p$ is a "non convex" distance ?)

Comment: @user352653 This is a particular case of the more general concept of $L^p(X)$, where $X$ is an arbitrary set. I don't know what a non-convex norm is.

Comment: Does $L^p\{0,1\}$ is the same that $\ell^p\{0,1\}$ ?

Comment: @user352653 Yes. I think that the notation $\ell^p$ is more common.